# How to use session cookie to connect to Gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab

The [gitlab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html#session-cookie) (just) says :

> When signing in to GitLab as an ordinary user, a _gitlab_session
>   cookie is set. The API will use this cookie for authentication if it
>   is present

I have the cookie on my browser but every request is still unauthorized. Is it supposed to automatically work ?

I try to send it with POST data with the name `gitlab_session` or `_gitlab_session` but no luck (authorization with credentials or private token works fine). I can't find any doc or examples anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't automatically work.

You need to create a new session using the `/session` API:

http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/session.html

You can also (maybe) pass the location to your cookie using curl (or your equivalent libararies) cookie function. An example with cURL would be:

```
curl "http://git.local/v3/api"
        --cookie "gitlab-cookies.txt"
        --cookie-jar "gitlab-cookies.txt"
```